# Getting the circle position on where the user clicks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, graphics

I have the following code which is supposed to be a circle game where if the user clicks inside the circle 2 times, the game will end. Or outside the circle (in total 7 click and the game will also end) and the circle will change its position. This is where I need some guidance and explanation on how to solve.

When I click outside the circle I need it to appear on the position where I clicked, and not just a random position in the window as it does now.
Please explain how I can approach this:)

```
import random
from graphics import *

def draw_circle(win, c = None):

    x = random.randint(0,600)
    y = random.randint(0,600)

    if c is None:
        centa = Point(x,y)
        c = Circle(centa,50)
        c.setFill(color_rgb(200,0,0))
        c.draw(win)
    else:
        center_x = c.p1.x + 50
        center_y = c.p1.y + 50
        x_dif = (center_x - x) * -1
        y_dif = (center_y - y) * -1
        c.move(x_dif, y_dif)
    return (c, x, y)

def circleGame():
    win= GraphWin("Click circles", 600, 600)
    totalClicks = 0
    var,x,y = draw_circle(win)
    clickInside = 0

    while totalClicks < 10 and clickInside < 3:
        totalClicks += 1
        mouseClick2 = win.getMouse()
        if mouseClick2.y >= y-50 and mouseClick2.y <= y +50 and \
mouseClick2.x >= x-50 and mouseClick2.x <= x+50:
            clickInside +=1
            totalClicks += random.randint(0,5)
        var,x,y = draw_circle(win, var)

circleGame()
```

thankyou so much in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `draw_circle` function is doing two separate things, so I'm not sure it makes sense to keep it as a single function. It's not updating the circle's x and y coordinates correctly because you're *always* returning random coordinates even when you should be returning the moved circle's coordinates. I've broken out the two parts of that function into the main `circle_game` function in my code below.

I've replaced your check for a click inside a square with a check for a click inside a circle: `(mouse.x - circle_x ) ** 2 + (mouse.y - circle_y) ** 2 <= CIRCLE_RADIUS_SQUARED`.

I also have no idea what `totalClicks += random.randint(0,5)` was trying to achieve.

```
import random

from graphics import *


def circle_game():
    CANVAS_WIDTH = 600
    CANVAS_HEIGHT = 600
    CIRCLE_RADIUS = 50
    CIRCLE_RADIUS_SQUARED = CIRCLE_RADIUS * CIRCLE_RADIUS

    window = GraphWin("Click circles", CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT)

    # Draw circle at random location to start game
    circle_x = random.randint(0, CANVAS_WIDTH)
    circle_y = random.randint(0, CANVAS_HEIGHT)
    circle_point = Point(circle_x, circle_y)
    circle = Circle(circle_point, CIRCLE_RADIUS)
    circle.setFill(color_rgb(200, 0, 0))
    circle.draw(window)

    total_clicks = 0
    inside_clicks = 0
    while total_clicks < 10 and inside_clicks < 3:
        mouse = window.getMouse()
        total_clicks += 1
        if (mouse.x - circle_x ) ** 2 + (mouse.y - circle_y) ** 2 <= CIRCLE_RADIUS_SQUARED:
            # Click was inside circle so we don't move circle
            inside_clicks +=1
        else:
            # Click was not inside circle so we move circle to mouse location
            dx = mouse.x - circle_x
            dy = mouse.y - circle_y
            circle.move(dx, dy)
            circle_x += dx
            circle_y += dy


if __name__ == '__main__':
    circle_game()
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `draw_circle` function, you're setting `x` and `y` to random values, and then doing `x_dif =(center_x - x) * -1` and `y_dif = (center_y - y) * -1`, so now you're basing the location on the random values `x` and `y`. And then you're returning those random values. Also, `x - center_x` is simpler than `(center_x - x) * -1`.

Another issue is `if mouseClick2.y >= y-50 and mouseClick2.y <= y +50 and
mouseClick2.x >= x-50 and mouseClick2.x <= x+50:`. That's both more complicated than you need, and not the test for a circle; it's the test for a square. You should have `(mouseClick2.y-y)**2+(mouseClick2.x-x)**2 <= 2500`.

Comment: I see, do you have any suggestions for the draw_circle issue?

Comment: @j.doesan I'm confused about several things about it, such as what `c.p1` means, why you're adding `50` to `c.p1.x` and `c.p1.y`, and why you're moving the circle instead of drawing a new one.